# PostGIS 2.0 Installation issues

Tags: postgresql, installation, gis, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have been trying to install postgis 2.0 on my computer(windows 7 32 bit) in order to benefit from expanded features. However I have been unable to actually get it to install successfully. My version of postgreSQL is 9.1.1-1, the most current windows 32 bit binary available.

When downloading postgis 2.0 the link to the download has the following instructions:

> For PostgreSQL 9.1 (compiled against PostgreSQL 9.1.0 - note 9.1 structure changed in beta 1 so this will not work with alpha releases but should be fine for all beta, release candidate releases and final 9.1.0 release) w/ Loader/Dumper including GUI. Also includes extensions files to install using new PostgreSQL

This implies to me that I need to get postgreSQL version 9.1.0 in order for Postgis to function correctly; however I cannot find the binaries for this version.

I tried installing on my 9.1.1 postgres install but it failed abysmally(when I ran the .bat file it just created a cascade stream of errors).

I have since just uninstalled postgres in order to ensure that the install isn't corrupt from all of my failed efforts, and deleted all the preexisting databases so that they will not show up again and possibly derail my install.

I suppose I could try building from source, but the [download page](http://postgis.refractions.net/download/windows/experimental.php) states the following with regard to that option:

> As many people know who have tried to build PostGIS binaries under windows, its a time consuming process to set up the environment and generally is rocket science

Needless to say I would like to avoid doing this at all costs, considering that I have never built anything from source before.

So, has anyone managed to actually get postgis 2.0 and all of its features up and running on a windows system? If so I would greatly appreciate it if you would share your install process with me as I am currently at a complete loss as to what to do (and yes I read the readmes that came with the installer)!

Comment: What about the StackBuilder? It should be part of the installation and includes PostGIS

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by  user1410317,

If you download the last version of Postgresql on at: http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Once done the installation you will be asked to continue with the Stack Builder... (Or you can open Stack Builder at any time going in Start/Programs/Postgresql xxx/) on Windows.

The Stack Builder wizard will guide you on the install process of extension for Postgresql... Just check the Postgis extension and you are done...

Very easy

Regards